# jquery Datatable all records Export to Excel

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to export all records of jquery datatable data to excel, but the issue is I am loading datatable partially, means on every page index change I make ajax request and loads data according to that.

Comment: No you can't do that with datatables because datatables read all the rows that are displayed.If you have large data its better to use smth else

Comment: Show us your code, your tries (always)... If the data is not loaded, it cannot be sent to an excel sheet. You could, when you create the excel sheet, load everything and write the file... ?

Comment: Had the same problem. I couldn't find a solution, except to show all records before exporting.